# How to run any jar file by a .bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, jar

My command is 
`java -jar my-jar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I want to create a bat file to run this command irrespective of the SNAPSHOT version.
This jar is located in the **D** drive  I have written this :

```
@ECHO ON
D:
cd "D:\Code\target"
java -jar my-jar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But the thing is when my SNAPSHOT version changes, again I have to edit the bat file. I there any command or way so that whatever the version is the bat file runs.

`java -jar my-jar-<any-version>-SNAPSHOT.jar`

or

`java -jar my-jar-<any-SNAPSHOT>.jar`

Comment: Is simply renaming the file not an option?

Comment: that is what I do @Mesalcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) — in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```cmd
for %I in ("D:\Code\target\my-jar-*-SNAPSHOT.jar") do @(pushd "%~dpI." && (java -jar "%~nxI" & popd))
```

Double the `%`-signs in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```cmd
for %%I in ("D:\Code\target\my-jar-*-SNAPSHOT.jar") do @(
    pushd "%%~dpI." && (
        java -jar "%%~nxI"
        popd
    )
)
```